# Google Map v3 - type of land

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

It is possible to check type of land in place where we have a marker? Eg. Water, park, road or something like this?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is available. You could probably tell if you're in water by using the http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/elevation/ elevation api - if it's a negative value you're under water!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. As GM is a raster map, I doubt you can do that (unless you analyze the pixel value).